# how to make this template code work from sheets app

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to make this script to work on google **sheets app** so it sends a pdf copy to my email when I type Send in cell L6
the code work perfect on computer but not on ipads , anyway to do this from app ?

```
function onEdit2(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r  = sheet.getRange('L6').getValue();
  if (r == "Send") {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    var ssID = ss.getId();
    var sheetgId = ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId();
    var sheetName = ss.getName();

    var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

    var email = "EMAIL HERE";
    var subject = "Daily report ";
    var body = "Please find the attached Daily report";

    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ssID+"/export?" 
      + "format=xlsx" +  "&gid="+sheetgId+ "&portrait=true" + 
      "&exportFormat=pdf";

    var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
      }
    });

    var contents = result.getContent();

    MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject ,body, {
      attachments: [{
        fileName: sheetName + ".pdf", 
        content: contents, 
        mimeType: "application//pdf"
      }]
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: I would just do this with a WebApp.  They run on anything.

Comment: Honestly, I thought about changing the whole google sheet into into webapp , but with my limited knowledge it seemed very complicated, any hints to put me on the right track ?       Here is a link of my sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1phZBkfEtZPocA0qtJnSA4v1pMLRZeCJwb8eKofHYVVo

Comment: Have you done any web site development? Do you know html,css,javascript,jquery?

Comment: I know little bit of HTML and I can use some program for Jquery

Comment: Well there are a lot of examples here on SO and while it might be a bit daunting for you at first in the end you will have empowered yourself to accomplish many more things.  I have several webapps that I do all kinds of things with.  I track vitaminK,Oxalate and fat consumption for all of my meals.  I track my bike rides with a gps app in my phone and then upload them to a WebApp for storing them in my exercise log.  One of the key reasons I wanted to learn apps script is that I like to do a lot simple stuff like this and I like it done my way.

Comment: So if you want to convert this sheet into web app where you start ? . Knowing you did all these apps made me wanted to know and learn :)

Comment: I'd build a simple dialog first and get that to work.  It's easier to test.  Once you get that to work moving to a webapp is a lot simpler.  My guess is that all you need is a button and perhaps a couple of text boxes.  So learn how to submit a form and your on your way.  You will want to read [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)  its the  key to client to server communications.  Stay with a bound script at first since your tied directly to a Spreadsheet.

Comment: Personally, I recommend that you read and try to understand the code samples for [custom dialogs & sidebars](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_dialogs).

Comment: I assume the function `onEdit2(e)` is actually named `onEdit(e)`, right? Otherwise, this cannot run as a simple trigger. Or you want to use an installed trigger?

Answer (score 1):

The way it worked for me by " installed Trigger " 
from the script editor : Edit - current project Triggers 
I added new trigger that will run the code below based on " On edit " and voila it worked , from sheets app if I typed " Send " in Cell L6 it will send a PDF copy of the active sheet to the email listed in the code.

```
function onEdit2(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r  = sheet.getRange('L6').getValue();
  if (r == "Send") {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    var ssID = ss.getId();
    var sheetgId = ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId();
    var sheetName = ss.getName();

    var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

    var email = "EMAIL HERE";
    var subject = "Daily report ";
    var body = "Please find the attached Daily report";

    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ssID+"/export?" 
      + "format=xlsx" +  "&gid="+sheetgId+ "&portrait=true" + 
      "&exportFormat=pdf";

    var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
      }
    });

    var contents = result.getContent();

    MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject ,body, {
      attachments: [{
        fileName: sheetName + ".pdf", 
        content: contents, 
        mimeType: "application//pdf"
      }]
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Google Script in the very same Spreadsheet or in another one (Tools / Script editor), add the script you already have, grant the authorizations required, and **trigger it with a simple form** (Tools / Create a form) (trigger → Edit / Current project's triggers). The long URL to view the form can be easily opened by means of a URL shortener or something by the sort. Forms work in cell phones too and without need to sign in to your account. With this method you can even add a useless conditional password to run the script.

```
function createPDF(e) {
  var input = e.values[1];
  if (input == 'my_password'){
    // your scripts to create and send the PDF goes here
  }
}
```

It's a simplistic solution, but it works.

Comment: Will this send the sheet as PDF or the form ?

Comment: Only if you include the sending MailApp.sendEmail lines in the Script. The programming is the same, but now triggered by means of a Google Form.